# angularJS expressions $scope.selectedTab = $scope.setTab(1) ? 1 : 2 ;

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why I can't use this expression?

```
$scope.selectedTab = $scope.setTab(1) ? 1 : 2 ;
```

setTab function:

```
$scope.setTab = function(tabNum) { 
    $scope.selectedTab = tabNum; 
    return $scope.selectedTab; 
}
```

Error message:

> TypeError: $scope.setTab is not a function

Comment: What is `$scope.setTab(1)` returning?

Comment: `$scope.setTab = function(tabNum) {
      $scope.selectedTab = tabNum;
      return $scope.selectedTab;
    }`

Comment: there is nothing wrong with that expression, what issues do you experience?

Comment: TypeError: $scope.setTab is not a function

Comment: Post the full code. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.` Otherwise the question is off-topic

Comment: @Pali you need to post your code ([_edit your post_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51018841/edit)), you are using it incorrectly and it's not clear how it can be fixed.

Comment: @Pali is `$scope.setTab` assigned before line with this expression?

Comment: feels like.. every time the ternary expression value would be truthy. 

$scope.selectedTab will always resolve in the value '1'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a declared function before it is declared. This will happen when the function is defined in the later part of the code.
When the $scope.setTab function is called, it would not have been defined.

The function has to be defined before the actual calling.

Fiddle

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ctrl);

function ctrl($scope){
  $scope.setTab = function(tabNum) { 
      $scope.selectedTab = tabNum; 
      return $scope.selectedTab; 
  }

  $scope.selectedTab = $scope.setTab(1) ? 1 : 2 ;
    console.log($scope.selectedTab);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gladson1976/n0r1v29e/6/